# Удаление столбиков с матрицы

Tags: java

Помогите пожалуйста. Есть массив чисел short A[7][7]. Нужно удалить с массива все столбики, в которых присутствует максимальный элемент массива(Например, если максимальный элемент массива это число 99, то нужно удалить все столбики, в которых присутствует число 99).

```
public class Main {

static short MAX = 0;

static void init(short[][] A) {
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < A[i].length; ++j) {
            A[i][j] = A[i][j] = (short) ((int) (Math.random() * 100));
        }
    }
}

static void Print(short[][] A) {
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < A[i].length; ++j) {
            System.out.print(A[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}


static void Search(short A[][]) {
    short max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < A.length; ++j) {
            if (A[i][j] > max) {
                max = A[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    MAX = max;
    System.out.println("Максимальный элемент в массиве: " + max);
}

static void DeleteByIndex(short A[][], int index) {
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < A[0].length - 1; j++) {
            if (j >= index - 1) {
                A[i][j] = A[i][j + 1];
            }
            System.out.print(A[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = 7;
    short[][] array = new short[N][N];
    init(array);
    Print(array);
    System.out.println();
    Search(array);

 }
}
```

Comment: а где код, который ты написал с ошибкой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main2 {


    static short MAX = 0;

    static void init(Short[][] A) {
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < A[i].length; ++j) {
                A[i][j] = A[i][j] = (short) ((int) (Math.random() * 100));
            }
        }
    }


    static void Search(Short A[][]) {
        short max = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < A.length; ++j) {
                if (A[i][j] > max) {
                    max = A[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        MAX = max;
        System.out.println("Максимальный элемент в массиве: " + max);
    }

    public static <T> T[] deleteElement(T[] src, int idx) {
        if (idx > src.length - 1)
            throw new RuntimeException("idx > src length");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] dest = (T[]) Array.newInstance(src[0].getClass(), src.length - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
            if (i < idx) {
                dest[i] = src[i];
            } else if (i > idx) {
                dest[i - 1] = src[i];
            }
        }
        return dest;
    }

    public static <T> T[][] deleteRow(T[][] src, int idx) {
        if (idx > src.length - 1)
            throw new RuntimeException("idx > src length");
        for (int i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
            src[i] = deleteElement(src[i], idx);
        }
        return src;
    }

    static <T> void print2DArray(T[][] src) {
        for (int i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(src[i]));
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 7;
        /*Short[][] array = {
                {1, 2, 3, 4},
                {11, 22, 33, 44},
                {111, 333, 333, 44},

        };*/

        Short[][] array = new Short[N][N];
        init(array);
        print2DArray(array);
        System.out.println();
        Search(array);

        int max;
        ArrayList<Integer> rowsIndex = new ArrayList<>();

        max = array[0][0];
        for (int r = 0; r < array.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < array.length; c++) {
                if (array[r][c] > max) {
                    max = array[r][c];
                }
            }
        }

        for (int r = 0; r < array.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < array.length; c++) {
                if (array[r][c] == max)
                    rowsIndex.add(c);
            }
        }

        int iter = 0;
        for (Integer c1 : rowsIndex) {
            array = deleteRow(array, c1 - iter);
/*            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                for (int c = c1; c < array.length - 1; c++)
                    array[i][c] = array[i][c + 1];
            }*/
            iter++;
        }

        print2DArray(array);

    }


}
```

вывод

```
[10, 27, 50, 60, 90, 9, 2]
[49, 33, 14, 80, 71, 30, 19]
[84, 6, 44, 34, 16, 40, 4]
[38, 19, 63, 0, 4, 37, 51]
[15, 26, 32, 65, 95, 0, 88]
[16, 89, 68, 94, 77, 54, 35]
[41, 1, 84, 71, 59, 94, 28]

Максимальный элемент в массиве: 95
[10, 27, 50, 60, 9, 2]
[49, 33, 14, 80, 30, 19]
[84, 6, 44, 34, 40, 4]
[38, 19, 63, 0, 37, 51]
[15, 26, 32, 65, 0, 88]
[16, 89, 68, 94, 54, 35]
[41, 1, 84, 71, 94, 28]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

вывод, когда несколько максимумов

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[11, 22, 33, 44]
[111, 333, 333, 44]

Максимальный элемент в массиве: 333
[1, 4]
[11, 44]
[111, 44]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Это не совсем то. Мне нужно удалить все столбики, в которых встречается максимальный элемент. Например здесь максимальный элемент это 333, но он может встречаться в матрице несколько раз. Тогда нужно удалить все столбики, в которых он находится.

Comment: @КириллСадовый исправил. сойдет ?